# at command not working due to cannot set egid error

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, centos7, chmod

I have a Dockerfile and I do:

```
RUN yum install -y at && chmod u+s /usr/bin/at
```

But when I actually try to run `at` inside the container I see in the logs

```
cannot set egid: Operation not permitted
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: @Philippe: The exact same error

Comment: Can you post a minimal Dockerfile ?